# Conflict with definition of "face"

Tags: convex-analysis, locally-convex-spaces, convex-geometry

I am given this definition of face from *Convexity: An analytic viewpoint*:

**Definition:** A face of a convex set $P$ is a set $F\subsetneq \overline{P}$ such that for every $x,y\in\overline{P}$ and for every $t\in(0,1)$, $tx+(1-t)y\in F \Rightarrow x,y\in F$.

But, I'm a little upset by this definition. We should hope that $F$ would be convex in every case. But, there's an easy counterexample. Take $F$ to be the extreme points of a triangle. Note that this is a valid face, as none of the points in $F$ are ever written as interior points. So the face property of this set is true by vacuity. Am I missing something here? Can we fix this by simply augmenting the definition to insist that $F$ is convex?

Comment: Isn't it that for convex, $t\in[0,1]$?

Comment: @Janus - we are talking about the face of a convex set, not a convex set itself. The definition boils down to this: $F$ is a face of $P$ if whenever $z\in F$ is an interior point along the line $[x,y]$, with $x,y\in\overline{P}$, then $[x,y]\subset F$.

Comment: The definition must include (or imply) that $F$ is itself convex. So the given property does not define a face. You give a nice counter example. In fact, the property as stated is conserved when taking any union.